Не корректно mib-дерево из файла net-snmp
Подсмотрел здесь код построения mib-дерева. Но вот проблема, дерево строится не так как я думаю. Вот часть вывода
"" 1   iso
" " 3   org
"  " 6   dod
"   " 1   internet
"    " 6   snmpV2
"     " 3   snmpModules
"      " 1   snmpMIB
"       " 2   snmpMIBConformance
"        " 2   snmpMIBGroups
"         " 10   snmpObsoleteGroup
"         " 12   snmpNotificationGroup
"         " 11   snmpWarmStartNotificationGroup
"         " 7   snmpBasicNotificationsGroup
"         " 6   systemGroup
"         " 5   snmpSetGroup
"         " 9   snmpCommunityGroup
"         " 8   snmpGroup
"        " 1   snmpMIBCompliances
"         " 3   snmpBasicComplianceRev2
"         " 2   snmpBasicCompliance
"       " 1   snmpMIBObjects
"        " 6   snmpSet
"         " 1   snmpSetSerialNo
"        " 5   snmpTraps
"         " 5   authenticationFailure
"         " 2   warmStart


Могу я как то получить дерево только необходимого mib файла?
Как вывести его в файл или модель?


Путь к файлу задаю так: char str[] = "/mibs/JETNEXUS-MIB.mib";
